# MQL4 Not enough memory for history data

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I have problem with getting time values for bar in higher timeframes. I'm testing my expert advisor in tester and when I try to use function **`iTime()`** with a **`PERIOD_D1`** parameter I always receive a value of  **`1970.01.01 00:00:00`**.

Also **`GetLastError()`** function returns a "`not enough memory for history data`" message. It repeats all time even though tester was running over a few days data. Bellow is code I try to run:

```
datetime t = iTime( Symbol(), PERIOD_D1, 0 );

Print( "Trend tick time: " + t );

int check1 = GetLastError();

if (  check1 != ERR_NO_ERROR ) Print( "Error: ", ErrorDescription( check1 ) );
```

And I'm getting output like this:

```
0 22:33:24 2016.06.29 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Trend tick time: 1970.01.01 00:00:00

0 22:33:24 2016.06.29 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Error: not enough memory for history data

0 22:33:25 2016.06.30 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Trend tick time: 1970.01.01 00:00:00

0 22:33:25 2016.06.30 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Error: not enough memory for history data

0 22:33:26 2016.07.01 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Trend tick time: 1970.01.01 00:00:00

0 22:33:26 2016.07.01 08:00 HLR FDE30,M1: Error: not enough memory for history data

[...]
```

And the same thing happens when I'm calling other build-in functions that take a timeframe parameter. Like for example **`iMA()`**, **`iCCI()`**, **`iRSI()`**.

Documentation suggests that above functions can accept any timeframe value: https://docs.mql4.com/series/itime

I'll just add that my MetaTrader Terminal chart settings are:

```
Max bars in history: 1250000
Max bars in chart:   1250000
```

Do you have any suggestions how I can resolve this problem?

Maybe there is some other setting or environmental restriction, I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not have space at your disk or no data.

In order to run a MetaTrader Terminal Strategy Tester, you need data, you may check it by pressing <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> and select a symbol and a timeframe.

If there are no data (i.e. at **`D1`** ) - press a <kbd>**`Download`**</kbd> button to get that data and then run the Strategy Tester again.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that MT4 ate all of your RAM memory.
(you can check it in "Task Menager", by pressing CTR+ALT+DEL)

**Solution**
Go to Tools -> Options -> "Max bars in chart"  and  set to 5000

...you probably had some huge number there.

..now restart MT4 and all good.